# MySQL count em substrings nas colunas de um campo varchar

Tags: mysql, count

Tenho a seguinte tabela de exemplo:

> ```
> ID_USER | FRUTAS
> -----------------------------
> 1       | Laranja;Banana;Maçã  
> 2       | Abacaxi;Laranja;Uva
> 3       | Pera;Laranja;Banana;Melão
> ```

Seria possível realizar um select count com order by que trouxesse o seguinte resultado:

> ```
> FRUTA       |   COUNT
> ---------------------------
> Abacaxi     |   1
> Banana      |   2
> Laranja     |   3
> Maçã        |   1
> Melão       |   1
> Pera        |   1
> Uva         |   1
> ```

Comment: Valeu pessoal, as respostas ajudaram bastante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta query irá retornar o que busca:

```
SELECT fruta, SUM(total) as count
FROM(
   SELECT count(*) AS total, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(x.fruta,'?',''),'.',''),'!','') as fruta
   FROM(
      SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.frutas, ';', n.n), ';', -1) fruta
      FROM tabela t CROSS JOIN 
      (
         SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
         FROM 
         (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
        ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
        ORDER BY n
      ) n
      WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.frutas) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.frutas, ';', '')))
      ORDER BY fruta
   ) AS x
   GROUP BY x.fruta
) AS y
GROUP BY fruta
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/229b3a/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi da seguinte forma, criei uma procedure onde, vou inserindo as frutas em uma tabela temporaria e no final faço uma query simples nessa tabela contando as `frutas`, o resultado é o esperado. considere que o nome da minha tabela é `frutas` e o nome do campo também caso precise alterar altere a `procedure` e rode em seu banco de dados.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_get_count_frutas;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_count_frutas()
BEGIN
DECLARE qtd_posicoes INT;
DECLARE end_cursor INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE qtd_aux INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE str_frutas VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE cur_frutas CURSOR   FOR SELECT
                                        frutas
                                FROM frutas;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET end_cursor = 1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_table_frutas;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table_frutas(fruta VARCHAR(255));
OPEN cur_frutas;
    REPEAT
        FETCH cur_frutas INTO str_frutas;
        IF NOT end_cursor THEN


            SET qtd_posicoes = (SELECT LENGTH(str_frutas) - LENGTH(REPLACE(str_frutas,';',''))) + 1;


            WHILE qtd_posicoes >= qtd_aux DO

                INSERT INTO tmp_table_frutas(fruta) VALUE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str_frutas, ';', qtd_aux),
                                                                                                        LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(str_frutas, ';', qtd_aux-1)) + 1),
                                                                                                        ';', ''));
                SET qtd_aux = qtd_aux + 1;
            END WHILE;

            SET qtd_aux = 1;

        END IF;
    UNTIL end_cursor END REPEAT;
CLOSE cur_frutas;

SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS total_fruta,
        fruta
FROM tmp_table_frutas
GROUP BY fruta;

END
|
DELIMITER ;

CALL sp_get_count_frutas();
```